# Missing required fields: customer.id, first_name, last_name

Tags: ontime

I'm busy integrating onTime API to one of our clients website. All my API requests are successfull (`GET, POST`).

But for some reason `POSTING` a new `/contacts` just always give me:

```
Missing required fields: customer.id, first_name, last_name
```

Although they are there correctly inserted as per the API documentation.
This is my json encoded data I'm posting:

`{"item":{"customer":{"id":6},"first_name":"CUSTOMER_NAME","last_name":"CUSTOMER_SURNAME","email":"someemail@website.com","phone":"1231231234"}}`

I'm out of ideas.

PS: I use an API class so the posting platform uses the same method throughout the project, and all my other posting of data works 100% it is just this action that is giving me issues.

Answer (score 0):

Ok,

I figured this one out also thanks to a fellow developer:

The problem was that the json object was encapsulated in the item{} object. This is incorrect. It should only be a single object of data like:

> {"customer":{"id":6},"first_name":"CUSTOMER_NAME","last_name":"CUSTOMER_SURNAME","email":"someemail@website.com","phone":"1231231234"}